# Exception in Spring MVC with Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having the hibernate-validator version 4.2.0.Final added in my spring mvc project. spring-webmvc version is 5.0.6.RELEASE. However, while launching the application, i see the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet fitTrackerServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader
  context: /FitnessTracker
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@279f2327
]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:262)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:638)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:554)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader
  context: /FitnessTracker
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@279f2327
]
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:245)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:638)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:554)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:245)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:638)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:554)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1928)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:245)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:638)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:686)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:554)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.86 logs.
```

Any Idea why this error comes? In code there is no problem. Just adding the jar causes this problem. Is there any compatibility issue between the two jars?

The pom.xml dependencies list and Maven Dependencies are shown below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: The validation-api version got added through transitive dependency is 1.0.0.GA. This version was not explicitly specified, but through hibernate-validator.

Comment: Looks like some dependency issue with one of the jars(most likely one of spring* jars) and hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final. After using the version 5.2.1.Final for Hibernate-Validator the issue got resolved. However i couldn't find any proof of the dependency issue with version 4.2.0.Final.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and had to exclude the JBoss provided javax.validation api classes. I did this by creating a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file that excluded not only the api classes, but modules that depend on them also. My file looked like:

```html
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api"/>
            <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
            <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javaee.api">
                <imports>
                    <exclude-set>
                        <path name="javax/ws/rs"/>
                        <path name="javax/ws/rs/core"/>
                        <path name="javax/ws/rs/ext"/>
                        <path name="javax/validation"/>
                        <path name="javax/validation/bootstrap"/>
                        <path name="javax/validation/constraints"/>
                        <path name="javax/validation/groups"/>
                        <path name="javax/validation/metadata"/>
                        <path name="javax/validation/spi"/>
                    </exclude-set>
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

After I deployed this with the WAR file, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, Tomcat Spring Boot App with a library that used both Hibernate validation (4.0) and Javax validation(1.0.0.GA).
But in my case Hibernate Validator was used inside a dependency and not directly in my project's pom. If upgrading the version on your pom doesn't work (or you just don't have that dependency in your POM to begin with), use DependencyManagement to ensure the correct versions are enforced for dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```